# getting absolute path of mount point in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, vfs

I'm currently working on enhancment to FAT file system implmentation in the linux kernel. I need to know just after a mount, what is the absolute path to the mount point. I tried different approaches, but it seems that the VFS mount and the actual mount are not binded. Does anyone has an idea how to accomplish that ?